# Make an Image turn Black and White on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I have a linked image and I want to make it turn black and white when the user hovers on it. Can anyone help please? I need to make it either with CSS or JavaScript. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
img.imgClass:hover {
    filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
    filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */
}
img.imgClass {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

Comment: Works on current Chrome

Answer (score 1):

```
img .imgClass:hover {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look for black and white "masks". [Here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS) is an article on that.

Answer (score -1):

In CSS 3 there is an spec for image filters, but this is not widly supported yet even in modern browsers:

```
img:hover {  
  filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE5+ */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Chrome Canary */

}
```

Instead you could make a black and white alternative for every image with this effect:

```
<a href="..."><img class="grayscale" src="..." /><img class="color" src="..." /></a>
```

With this CSS: (not tested)

```
a img.grayscale {
  display: none;
}
a:hover img.color {
  display: none;
}
a:hover img.grayscale {
  display: block;
}
```

Default the grayscale image is hidden, on hover the colored one gets hidden and the grayscale one gets shown.

Comment: Bad advice to create 2 different imagesets to load for the page